# how to create dynamic tab in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a list of tabs on tabPanel and i want to add another tab on it,when the condition is true,is that possible,if yes then let me know how to do it.
ex. the code in Mycontroller page is:

```
mylist:funtion()
{
 if(mylist[0]=='Deployment_model')
 { 
 Ext.getCmp('') //here i want that one tab should me added on the view page
 }
 else{
  //do something
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add another item to tabbed panel.
Have a look at this fiddle : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#5j3yu

```
Ext.getCmp("mytabpanel").add({
                                title: 'New',
                                iconCls: 'action',

                                items: [
                                    {
                                        docked: 'top',
                                        xtype: 'panel',
                                        html: 'This is new content'
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
```

Comment: I have already added another item to tab panel but, it should hide and show whenever the condition is true and false respectively.